# game maker GML twin stick shooter analogue controller

Tags: gml

I am trying to make a twin stick shooter but I cannot get right analogue stick to shoot in the correct direction. Here is the code I have the weapon sits on top of the player and rotates. It all works fine just need to know how to get the correct angle of the right stick and fire a bullet in that direction.

```
     //set depth
    depth = -y + obj_player.y_off_set - 1;

    //analog left stick face direction
    var h_point = gamepad_axis_value(0, gp_axisrh);
    var v_point = gamepad_axis_value(0, gp_axisrv);

    if ((h_point != 0) || (v_point != 0))
    {
    var pdir = point_direction(0, 0, h_point, v_point);
    var dif = angle_difference(pdir, image_angle);
    image_angle += median(-20, dif, 20);
    }

    //flips gun when turning 
    if(gamepad_axis_value(0, gp_axisrh) < -0.5)
    {
    image_yscale = -1;
    }else if (gamepad_axis_value(0, gp_axisrh) > 0.5)
    {
    image_yscale = 1;
    }

//fireing
fire = gamepad_button_check_pressed(0, gp_shoulderr) && alarm[0] <= 0;


if(fire)
{

    var face = point_direction(0, 0, gp_axisrh, gp_axisrv);   

    var p = instance_create(x, y, obj_projectile);
    var xforce = lengthdir_x(20, face*90);
    var yforce = lengthdir_x(20, face*90);
    p.creator = id;
    with (p){

    physics_apply_impulse(x, y, xforce, yforce);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

as this question is a couple months old, I imagine you found the solution to your problem, but hopefully this answer can help anyone else stuck on the issue.

Based on the code snippet you provided, it looks like if you remove the ***90** from the lengthdir_ functions, your code should work.

Here is the code I wrote in my game to get 360 degree shooting working with the right analog stick (this code lives in the step event of the Player object):

```
if (shooting) {
    bullet = instance_create(x, y, Bullet);

    with (bullet) {
        haxis = gamepad_axis_value(0, gp_axisrh);
        vaxis = gamepad_axis_value(0, gp_axisrv);
        dir = point_direction(0, 0, haxis, vaxis);

        physics_apply_impulse(x, y, lengthdir_x(50, gp_axisrh), lengthdir_y(50, dir));
    }
}
```

This [particular thread](https://forum.yoyogames.com/index.php?threads/analog-stick-replacing-mouse.23402/) on the GameMaker community forums was quite helpful as I researched how to solve this issue in my game.